# Custom Listfield doesn't draw correctly

Tags: blackberry, alignment, listfield

I added a custom listfield component using BSimpleTable which I got from here :
http://javaandjava.blogspot.com/2010/02/simple-table-component-for-blackberry.html
Unfortunately the component doesn't support right alignment for the fields inside it, so I tried to added it by modifying the code, like this :

```
public class BSimpleRowRenderer extends Manager{
private int[] colWidthPercents;
private int[] cellFrontPaddings;
private int preferredHeight;

public BSimpleRowRenderer(long style,Field[] rowContents,int preferredHeight, 
 int[] colWidthPercents,int[] cellFrontPaddings){
    super(style);
    for (int col = 0; col < rowContents.length; col++) {
        add(rowContents[col]);
    }
    this.colWidthPercents = new int[rowContents.length];
    for(int i=0;i<colWidthPercents.length;i++){
        this.colWidthPercents[i] = colWidthPercents[i];
    }
    this.cellFrontPaddings = new int[rowContents.length];
    for(int i=0;i<cellFrontPaddings.length;i++){
        this.cellFrontPaddings[i] = cellFrontPaddings[i];
    }
    this.preferredHeight = preferredHeight;
}

protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
    int x=0;
    int totalWidth = Display.getWidth();
    for (int col = 0; col < getFieldCount(); col++) {
        // Set the size and position of the current cell.
        Field curCellField = getField(col);
        XYPoint offset = calcAlignmentOffset(curCellField, Math.max(0,colWidthPercents[col]*totalWidth/100), Math.max(0, getPreferredHeight()));
        layoutChild(curCellField, width-x,getPreferredHeight());
        setPositionChild(curCellField, x+offset.x, 0);
        x+=(int)Math.floor((colWidthPercents[col]*totalWidth)/100); 
    }
    setExtent(Display.getWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
}

public void drawRow(Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    layout(width, height);
    setPosition(x, y);
    g.pushRegion(getExtent());
    subpaint(g);
    g.popContext();
}

public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return Display.getWidth();
}

public int getPreferredHeight() {
    return preferredHeight;
}

private XYPoint calcAlignmentOffset(Field field, int width, int height)
{
    XYPoint offset = new XYPoint(0, 0);
    long fieldStyle = field.getStyle();
    long field_x_style = fieldStyle & Field.FIELD_HALIGN_MASK;

    if (field_x_style == Field.FIELD_RIGHT){
        offset.x = width - field.getExtent().width;
    }
    else if (field_x_style == Field.FIELD_HCENTER){
        offset.x = (width - field.getExtent().width) / 2;
    }

    long field_y_style = fieldStyle & Field.FIELD_VALIGN_MASK;

    if (field_y_style == Field.FIELD_BOTTOM){
        offset.y = height - field.getExtent().height;
    }
    else if (field_y_style == Field.FIELD_VCENTER){
        offset.y = (height - field.getExtent().height) / 2;
    }

    return offset;
}
```

}

The problem is, the right alignment is only working for fields inside highlighted row or row which have been highlighted.
I wonder where have I done wrong or missed in the above code.
I'm in real desperate now as to any modification doesn't reflect what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

If table is what you need, then you could try this: [How To - Create a rich UI layout with TableLayoutManager](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800508/How_To_-_Create_a_rich_UI_layout_with_TableLayoutManager.html?nodeid=1906675&vernum=0). It worked for me perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but changing the component is the last thing I want to do, the current component is good enough except for the lack of the right alignment support.
Thanks anyway.